# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry time travels and is de-aged to 10, the same age as James

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, time-travel, fan-fiction

I can’t find this fanfic I read a couple years ago. I remember the following details:

1. Harry goes back in time and is de-aged to 10 and is the same age as James
2. He claims he is the son of Charlus Potter’s lost sister
3. He is adopted by the Potters
4. Voldemort thinks Harry is his grandson

Comment: *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* by Jack Thorne?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be ***[Ripples in Time](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3143742/1/Ripples-in-Time)*** (2006) by padfootsrevenger.

> Harry is victorious and Voldemort is gone, but not all is as it should be. Thrown into the past Harry takes on the role of James Potter’s long lost cousin and attempts to do the one thing Hermione always warned him about. Is this a second chance or curse?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. We'd appreciate it if you edited this answer to explain why you think the fanfic the OP was looking for might be  "Ripples in Time," though, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't. It'd help the OP and other users decide how likely this answer is to be correct or not.